# Django multiple tag field

Tags: python, django, tags, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to find a good tutorial for django how to create multiple tags in a model.

For example:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Sample(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   urlA  = models.CharField()
   urlB  = models.CharField()
   tagA = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
   tagB = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I would like to display the tags as an input field and separate by ',' and split in the save method. So I'd like to see 2 different input for the 2 tag field.

If you have an easy way to do or know a good tutorial, please tell me! :)

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you do not have to have the actual table sets over laid. You can generate any queryset you want to inn your views. Your url conf can be set up to display the detail view from multiple url. If i am still not understanding then please refine your question.

For having multiple anything tags categories your either going m21 or m2m. So when you create your tags you can add them one by one. Are you familiar with what the Django ORM has to offer with some of its admin functionality? Please give the documentation a good look through. Your approach to this problem is anything but reasonable. Not trying to rub you the wrong way I'm no genius. You would do something like so.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "tags"
        ordering = ['title']

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
     return "/tags/%s/" % self.slug

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToMany('Tag')
    slug = models.SlugField()


    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/%s/" % self.slug
```

There's a little more code to be done for the EntryAdmin and the TagAdmin models, Many other things that can be done as well. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that if you could be more clear? Thank you, the above is a rough illustration of how I would approach it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I would like to join the tag table 2 times to the model. I need two (later more than two) URL field and I wan't 2 (later more) differet tag list for every one. I need 2 cross table.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, because from my angle your approach does not seem close to right. I understand your approach. What is it you're trying to do that you would need two sets of tags for each model? I use django-tagging so to me its as simple as tags = TagField(). Then in my model edit instance I can enter tags in a comma separated list, this beats the approach I showed as you as it has more features and you don't have to keep pressing the plus button to add another m2m tag relationship to that instance.

Comment: Yes, I wan't two (and more) sets of tags in the model. If I use the tagging my only work is tagA = TagField() and tabB = TagField() and i can handle it by forms on the site and automaticly in the admin? For now I don't want use it in the admin. (sorry for the slow answer I have had a lot of work)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from here:
https://dev.to/thepylot/how-to-add-tags-to-your-models-in-django-django-packages-series-1-3704

**django-taggit** is very useful for tagging.

It is

> a reusable application that primarily offers you a Tag model, and a manager for easily adding tags to any model.
>
> ```
> pip install django-taggit
> ```

After that, open settings.py and edit the installed apps section:

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>     ...
>     'taggit' 
> ]
> ```

After that, edit your model and add tags like this:

```
tags = TaggableManager()
```

> The TaggableManager will show up automatically as a field in a ModelForm or in the admin.

Documentation: https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html